# Making folders hide and unhide

Tags: applescript, hide, show, directory

I am trying to make a command to hide and show folders on my desktop this is my code so far in applescript:

```
on run
    if "chflags hidden ~/Desktop/*" then
        do shell script "chflags nohidden ~/Desktop/*"
    else
        do shell script "chflags hidden ~/Desktop/*"
    end if
end run
```

Can u please find the problem and help
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command seems to work as expected. I tested it with a folder on my desktop, so

```
chflags hidden ~/Desktop/testDir/*
chflags nohidden ~/Desktop/testDir/*
```

does the job.

Your if-statement doesn't work.

```
if "chflags hidden ~/Desktop/*" then
```

That does nothing. Even if you would add the missing "do shell script":

```
if (do shell script "chflags hidden ~/Desktop/testDir/*") then
```

That will actually hide everything (which you don't want at this point) and it returns nothing and that generates an AppleScript-Error.

So you have to look for another way to check for the hidden state.

Here's a code sample to do that:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set filePath to file (((path to desktop) as text) & "myReferenceFile.txt")
end tell

set this_info to info for filePath
if visible of this_info is true then
    log "VISIBLE"
else
    log "INVISIBLE"
end if
```

If you have a reference file you could use that path to check if it's hidden or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle the flags with something like this:

```
property hideFolders : true

if hideFolders then
    do shell script "find ~/Desktop/* -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec chflags hidden {} +"
    set hideFolders to false
else
    do shell script "find ~/Desktop/* -type d -maxdepth 1 -exec chflags nohidden {} +"
    set hideFolders to true
end if
```